Docker Samba Server - Unable to Connect from Other Devices
I'm running a dockurr/samba Docker container on my Apple M2 Pro machine. I can successfully access the Samba share from the host machine (using Finder/Connect to Server), but I'm unable to connect to it from other devices on the same local network (e.g., another computer, Android TV).
Here's my Docker Compose configuration:
samba:
  image: dockurr/samba
  container_name: samba
  hostname: samba
  environment:
    NAME: ${SAMBA_NAME}
    USER: ${SAMBA_USER}
    PASS: ${SAMBA_PASS}
  ports:
    - ${SAMBA_PORT_445}:445
  volumes:
    - ${PATH_TO_MEDIA_FOLDER}:/storage

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:
Verified firewall rules: Ensured that the firewall on my host machine allows incoming connections on port 445.
Restarted services: Restarted Docker and the Samba service within the container.
Checked network connectivity: Confirmed that both the host machine and the other devices are on the same network.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this connection issue.

Update
For the record, the issue was that I should have set the fixed IP address on the router and not on the computer. Thank you all who have given me answers and ideas. I should have asked this question on Server Fault.

From other devices, run nc -vz macos-IP 445 to confirm connectivity. You may post mount command and error messages .

You need to expose the relevant ports on the host IP. You can do that using the -p switch to docker run.
For example:
docker run -p 445:445 container

The above will map port 445 on the local host to the docker container. Make sure nothing else is listening on the same port.

Docker documentation about bridge networking(https://docs.docker.com/engine/network/drivers/bridge/) :
For Docker, a bridge network uses a software bridge which allows containers connected to the same bridge network to communicate, while providing isolation from containers which are not connected to that bridge network.
Docker documentation about host networking (https://docs.docker.com/engine/network/drivers/host/) :
If you use the host network driver for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host. For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 445 and you use host networking, the container’s application will be available on port 445 on the host’s IP address.
If you want to deploy multiple containers connected between them with a private internal network use bridge networking. If you want to deploy a container connected to the same network stack as the host (and access the same networks as the host) use host networking. And, if you want to publish some ports, run the container with the --publish or -p option, such as -p 445:445.
For example, you can try this docker-compose file to expose the container on the host network (the same as your computer is exposed).
samba:
  image: dockurr/samba
  container_name: samba
  hostname: samba
  environment:
    NAME: ${SAMBA_NAME}
    USER: ${SAMBA_USER}
    PASS: ${SAMBA_PASS}
  ports:
    - ${SAMBA_PORT_445}:445
  volumes:
    - ${PATH_TO_MEDIA_FOLDER}:/storage
  network_mode : host

